# How to select $\lambda$ such that $P_{X\sim Pois(\lambda)}( X \geq x) > \delta$ for any $\delta$ and $x$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Consider a Poisson variable with parameter $\lambda$: 
$$
X \sim Pois(\lambda)
$$
For an arbitrary $\delta > 0.5$ and $x \in (1, \infty)$ is there a simple way to select $\lambda$ such that we always have: 
$$
P(X \geq x) > \delta
$$

**Here is an effort:**
$$
\sum_{k=x}^{\infty}\frac{\lambda^k e^{-\lambda} }{k!} \geq \delta
$$
Simplfiying this equation is tricky. Since we know that $\delta>0.5$, $x$ should be close to $\lambda$ or smaller. Wondering if I can find a simple expression.

Comment: Is there another criterion on $\lambda$? Like "the smallest value such that", etc.

Comment: Yeah, but even if I don't say that assumption it should be fine since I am asking it for any $x$ and $\delta$.

Comment: Unless you choose a trivial answer like $\lambda = \infty$

Answer (score 1):

$$
\sum_{k=x}^{\infty}\frac{\lambda^k e^{-\lambda} }{k!} \geq \delta
$$

We other approach is to use the Chernoff bound: 
$$
P(X \leq x) \leq \frac{e^{-\lambda} (e \lambda)^x}{x^x}, \text{ for } x < \lambda.
$$
Using the second inequality, we have: 
$$
P(X > x) = P(X \geq x+1) \geq 1 - \frac{e^{-\lambda} (e \lambda)^x}{x^x}, \text{ for } x < \lambda.
$$
Hence:
$$
P(X \geq x) \geq 1 - \frac{e^{-\lambda} (e \lambda)^{x-1}}{(x-1)^{x-1}}, \text{ for } x < \lambda-1.
$$
We set: 
$$
1 - \frac{e^{-\lambda} (e \lambda)^{x-1}}{(x-1)^{x-1}} \geq \delta \Rightarrow 1 - \delta  \geq  \frac{e^{-\lambda} (e \lambda)^{x-1}}{(x-1)^{x-1}} 
$$

$$
\Rightarrow \log(1 - \delta)  \geq   -\lambda + (x-1)(1+ \log \lambda) - (x-1) \log (x-1) 
$$

Simplifying it a little more: 
$$
\Rightarrow \log(1 - \delta)  \geq   (x-1) \left[(1+ \log \lambda) - \log (x-1) \right]  - \lambda
$$